# Recover unsaved code in spyder IDE with history log

Tags: python, spyder

Spyder crashed but I didn't saved the code I was working on. When I restarted Spyder, obviously my code was gone. I found out, that I somehow can get the code back with the command `hist -g`. I have tried this, but this only allows me to see statements like this: runfile('XXXX', wdir='XXX')
Is there a way to get my code back? Despite of one other question on stackoverflow i couldnt find anything related to my problem.

[Sorry if I understood something completly wrong or if I have grammar- or spellingerros. This is my first coding internship and English is not my native language, I'll try to improve both in the future :)]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately there's no way to do that if you were working in an untitled file. If that was not the case, you should have been prompted with a dialog to restore your open files before the crash, unless you were working with a very old Spyder version (i.e. Spyder 3).

Comment: Another option is to look for a pane called `History`, which contains the last 1000 commands you introduced in the console.

Comment: But how can you recover code from commands?